# Spl_autoload_register() not working on server

Tags: php

I made a simple autoloader using spl_autoloader_register function, it works fine on my virtual server, but in the server I only got "Fatal Error: Class 'X' not found". Im running it on a mac with PHP 5.4, but it also works in windows/ubuntu with 5.3 version, which is the same as my physic server. I don't have SSH access to it. Here is my autoload code:

```
class Load
{   
    public static function autoload($class)
    {    
        $class = strtolower($class);        
        $lib =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . BASENAME . "/libs/{$class}.php";        
        $model =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . BASENAME . "/models/{$class}.class.php";  
        $controller =  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . BASENAME . "/controllers/{$class}.php";  

        if(is_readable($lib)){
            require_once $lib;  
        }elseif (is_readable($model)) {
            require_once $model;        
        }elseif (is_readable($controller)){
            require_once $controller;
        }
    }

}
spl_autoload_register("Load::autoload");
```

I always used spl for local apps, but its the first time I'm trying it on the server.
Any advice for better practices will be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: Check the return value of `spl_autoload_register`. If it's `FALSE`, something went wrong with the registering.

Comment: I put an else in the condition, and it stopped there, so its failing the is_readable, but the path/filename its right, besides, if was the path, it should not work local, right?

Comment: Make sure your `$lib`, `$model` and `$controller` variables contain the right path.

Comment: It is, because it works local

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710480/php-spl-autoload-register

Comment: the spl_autoload_register has no arguments because the class is also the name of the file, so it should work, also it works local

Comment: Is $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] set on your server?
This var also can be contain a trailing slash depending on server configuration. Its better to use a constant where you have defined the include path.

Comment: An autoloader is meant to be used according to PSR-0. http://www.php-fig.org/psr/0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good practice can be to add your own include path. Then you can disclaim $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].
For example..

```
// Define path to library
define('MY_LIBRARY_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../insert_path_here_relativly'));

// Ensure library is on include_path
set_include_path(
    get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . MY_LIBRARY_PATH
);
```

Then your autoloader..

```
class Load
{   
    public static function autoload($class)
    {    
        $class = strtolower($class);        
        $lib =  MY_LIBRARY_PATH . "/libs/{$class}.php";        
        $model = MY_LIBRARY_PATH . "/models/{$class}.class.php";  
        $controller = MY_LIBRARY_PATH . "/controllers/{$class}.php";  

        if(is_readable($lib)){
            require_once $lib;  
        }elseif (is_readable($model)) {
            require_once $model;        
        }elseif (is_readable($controller)){
            require_once $controller;
        }
    }

}
spl_autoload_register("Load::autoload");
```

Comment: `is_readable($file)` returns TRUE if file either a dir or a regular file. So what if it was a directory, like `/foo/bar.php`? Then `require_once()` will attempt to include a directory, jeez!

Comment: And also, this class is full of bad practices, including global state and tight-coupling. Also, `spl_load_register()` is a part of `Load` class, thus it should be implemented within a method that belongs in the class.

Comment: Yeah you are right, but its a simply way to build an own autoloader.
You can also use is_file in additional to check on real file.
Its better to build a real Loader class, with namespacing, more than one directories and so on.

Comment: Yes, that looks fine.